# Tensorflow running at 35% GPU utilization, profiler shows odd cpu activity

Tags: profiling, tensorflow

I'm running a typical 5 layer convolutional network on the GPU in tensorflow. When I run on a fast 1080 TI GPU I'm getting about 35% GPU utilization. On a slower M40 I get 80% utilization and get 97% utilization on a 970m mobile GPU.

I've implemented the tf.StagingArea GPU queue and have confirmed with a warning message that StagingArea is not empty before each training step, it's being feed asynchronously.

I've run the tensorflow profiler seen below. Notably, the main operations on the GPU appear to complete in 15ms, but then there's a gap between 15ms and 40ms where nothing is registered by the profiler. At 40ms three small CPU operations occur that appear related to the optimizer (global step update).

This behavior is consistent at every step.

Any idea why there's such a delay here?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a way how you can determine what is happening on CPU inside of that interval with help of Intel VTune Amplifier (the tool is not free, but there are free fully functional academic and trial versions). You can use a recipe from [this article](https://software.intel.com/ru-ru/articles/profiling-tensorflow-workloads-with-intel-vtune-amplifier) to import timeline data to Intel VTune Amplifier and analyze it there. You will need Frame Domain / Source Function grouping. Expand [No frame domain - Outside any frame] row and you will get the list of hotspots happening in the interval you are interested in.